# wsearch preventing USB storage ejection

Tags: windows-8, usb, windows-8.1, sd-card

I've just upgraded to 8.1, and when trying to eject an SD card from the computer (via 'Safely remove hardware'), I get this message:

```
The application 'wsearch' is preventing this device from being stopped. Close the application and try to stop the device again.
```

Presumably wsearch is a windows search background task, but how can I close it/force it to let go of my SD card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well running a system scan fixed this

```
sfc /scannow
```